# Problem Report issue

Tags: 12.10

I have been getting this issue ever since I installed 12.10 on my computer, it drives me to see a pop-up that said Report a issue or something in does lines, Is there a way I can take rid of it for good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're refering to Apport

> Apport is an Error Reporting Service provided by Ubuntu to intercept
>   and analyse crashes and bugs as and when they occur. Crashes and Bugs
>   may sound like bad things, but actually most operating systems will
>   have several a day, and it doesn't mean your computer is broken, nor
>   does it necessarily stop working. As such, Apport can usually be
>   safely disabled, as it doesn't fix anything, it just tells developers
>   that something went wrong.

All the commands below require that you open Terminal to run the commands.  To open Terminal, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard.  When it opens, run the command(s) below:

You can stop Apport for the running session with:

```
sudo service apport stop
```

To disable, you have to edit the apport file, and Change the line that says `enabled=1` to `enabled=0`

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/apport
```

Or you can remove Apport:

```
sudo apt-get purge apport
```

**Note:** I personally don't recommend that you disable it.

<sup>Source: How to Ubuntu</sup>

Comment: I been trying to find the error but the only thing wrong with it is just a flashing screen in the display.

Comment: You can try looking in the log file ` /var/log/apport.log`